# Android Studio doesn't open project correctly (Android project view)

Tags: android, android-studio

my Problem is that whenever I open a project in Android Studio which I have not created myself, it doesn't load the project in the way I can simply run it.

[image]

In the above screenshot the Android projet view doesn't show anything as it usually should be...
When I load a project a created myself, there is no problem. Can anyone help? I'm a total Android beginner and want to be able to look into other projects AND run them.

Dan

Comment: it's happens, problem is with your project directory

Comment: but how do I fix that?

Comment: you are using android studio 1.3.1,update your android studio and try again...

Comment: @DaDarkDan, please post your project directory structure available in your computer which you browse, during import project in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot looks like there is no project open at all; once a project is open, at least in Android Studio 2.2, there should at least be two items in the Project pane: 'app' and 'Gradle Scripts'.

[image]

From there, the `MainActivity.java` that you're used to initially seeing can be accessed via `app/java/com.xxx/MainActivity` and `layout.xml` files can be accessed via `app/res/layout/activity_main.xml` etc.